# K2 URLs not working after migration to Joomla 3

Tags: k2, url, sef, .htaccess-configuration

I've just migrated to Joomla 3 and my K2 URLs are returning 404's.

Before the migration this was an example of a correct URL: [url=https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/7687-o-que-significa-mass-customization.html]URL[/url]

After the migration, this page opens with this URL: [url=https://www.portal-gestao.com/slideshow/item/7687-o-que-significa-mass-customization.html]URL[/url]

So, the category is now behind the /item/ part of the URL.

It is very important, for SEF reasons, to preserve the old URL structure. I had the following line in .htaccess to force all K2 items to that structure:

```
RewriteRule ^.+/item/(.+)$ /item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How can I bring this URL structure back?

Help please!

Comment: You can try to go to Menu Manager and and click Rebuild button to see if it helps.

Comment: So, you need all of your K2 pages to load with just item/alias instead of using the category/item/alias? Did you, also, upgrade K2? Since you mention SEF, the new version of K2 has many more SEF settings that allow you to get rid of the "item" non-sense.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

When in K2 (in the Joomla admin), click on `Parameters` on the top right, and then click on the `Advanced` tab. Under `Advanced SEF Settings`, choose "Yes" next to `Enable advanced SEF for K2 URLs` and then choose "None" next to `Prefix for item URLs`. For good measures, choose "No" next to `Use the category ID in the URL` and choose "No" next to `Use the category title alias`.